# Deleting messages from icloud except for those stored on iphone

Tags: iphone, mac, icloud, messages, messages-in-icloud

I have synced my phone's messages with icloud. A few months ago I hit the storage limit of 5GB and the messages stopped being uploaded to icloud. When I got a mac, it downloaded my messages from icloud and the latest messages were from a few months ago (as expected).

Today I deleted around 3GB of photos and videos from iMessages, but it still shows 5GB full on icloud. Do I need to do anything to fix this? Or will my phone, mac, and icloud automatically sync together, deleting all those photos and videos I deleted from my phone's messages?

[image]
[image]

Comment: How much time has elapsed between deleting the content and looking at the storage?

Comment: not much, an hour or two perhaps.

Comment: It takes a day or two for that screen to be updated, based on your device usage. You can also check icloud.com to see if it's updated.